# How to config custom addons path in odoo 14 on mac?

Tags: macos, odoo

I want to add a custom addons folder to my Odoo app, so I can create new apps. I found an Odoo.conf file but adding path does not work there! I searched and realized that I should find a file named .odoorc but I could not find this file in my system. what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself.
you have to add a parameter in config[image: -c config path which is located in Debian folder]

and after that customize your odoo.config file in the Debian folder. add the custom addons folder path.